# MySQL Full Text Search Relevance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I would like to have my search like this.

Must **"always" match** a result in either title, catgory or tags for the word **massive** otherwise return no results.

If it find words **massive and big** in any/either title, catgory or tags **rank higher** that just (massive)

If matches **massive and huge** in any/either title, catgory or tags then **rank even higher** than just (massive) and (massive and big)

I would also like to **ignore words**, even if the word massive exists I dont want to return a row that matches **small, tiny or miro** in either title category or tags.

Also all words should be matched if the word is the begining of another word so for example **biggest should match with the word big** and **smallest should match with the word small**

So just to simplify...

Order of matched words, highest rank first:

Massive and huge
Massive and big
Massive

Ignore these:

small
tiny
micro

This is what I have but I don't know if its correct as i'm quite new to this.

```
MATCH(title,categorys,tags) AGAINST('+massive* huge* big* -small -tiny -micro' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 14
```

And this is my mysql indexes

```
Table  key_name Seq_in_index  column_name cardinality Null  Index_type
videoz title    1             title         1         YES   FULLTEXT        
videoz title    2             categorys     1         YES   FULLTEXT        
videoz title    3             tags          1         YES   FULLTEXT
```

Am I on the right track, thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use `>huge` and `<big` to increase and lower the importance of the words, although you don't have 100% control over what the value will finally be. If you really need that, you can use several `match against`, and then multiply them with a weight (e.g. `(match...against...)*5+(match...against...)*2`, but it will be slower. On the other hand, if you `order by rand()`, it kinda defeats the purpose of defining which combination of words is more important than the other.

Comment: Thanks in that case as I dont want it to be too slow i think ill just find words, massive huge and big and ignore small, tiny and mirco. But I notice with my code it still finds records with the word small, my code must be wrong but i don't know why.